# Retrieving .data() works if element referenced by $(this) but not when by $('#id_of_element')

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and need to add `.data()` to the element inside the plugin and retrieve it later. When I run the method on an element I cannot retrieve the stored data when referencing the element by its id like:

```
$('#name_of_the_element')
```

I can access the data if I reference the element using `$(this)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code of the jQuery plugin and the code of the html file that I use it in:

jQuery plugin:

```
(function( $ ){

    var methods = {

        checkit : function(options) {

            return this.each(function(){

                var $this = $(this);

                $this.data('testdata','this is what i need to see');

            }); 
        }


    }

  $.fn.demoplug = function( method ) {        
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.checkit.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.antigravity' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

HTML file:

```
<div role="main" id="main">
    <ul id="miniatures">
        <li><img src="img/thumbs/thumb-01.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="img/thumbs/thumb-02.jpg"></li>            
        <li id="mov3"><img src="img/thumbs/thumb-03.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="img/thumbs/thumb-04.jpg"></li>            
        <li><img src="img/thumbs/thumb-05.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.demoplug.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('li#mov3').demoplug('checkit');

        alert( $('li#mov3').data('checkit') );  // not working

        $('li#mov3').click(function(){

            alert( $(this).data('testdata') );  // works

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: from what I can see, it's simply because there is no data attached called 'checkit'.

Answer (score 1):

```
    alert( $('li#mov3').data('checkit') );  // not working
```

it's because you're fetching the 'checkit' key in data but you set the key as 'testdata':

```
    $this.data('testdata','this is what i need to see');
```

change it to this would work:

```
    alert( $('li#mov3').data('testdata') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the error was in the wrong place! I extracted this code from the plug i'm working on to show the place which i THOUGHT was wrong, but the real error was that inside the plugin i'm using .clone() method and my wrong usage of .clone() method made this error - it doubled the ID of the LI elements so that i got 2 LIs with id="mov3". I didn't read enough documentation to see what things are cloned when using .clone(). Thank you guys for answering!